# Target last word and wrap with span class

Tags: javascript

I am trying to target the last word within a class and then wrap it with a span so that I can style the last word using Javascript.

```
<h1 class="title>A long tile</h1>
<h2 class="title>A long tile</h2>
```

becomes

```
<h1 class="title>A long <span class="last-word">tile</span></h1>
<h2 class="title>A long <span class="last-word">tile</span></h2>
```

I've seen some jQuery solutions on Stack which helped a bit, but I'd like a JS version.

I can get this working for the first element on the page, using this code…

```
var paras = document.querySelector('.title');

function wrapLastWord(elem) {
  const textContent = elem.textContent.split(" ");
  const lastWord = textContent.pop();

  // if the sentence is more than 1 word, wrap the last word with a span. If it's only 1 word, return it without being wrapped by a span
  const updatedContent = textContent.join(" ") + (textContent.length > 0 ? ` <span class='last-word'>${lastWord}</span>` : lastWord);

  elem.innerHTML = updatedContent;
}

wrapLastWord(paras)
```

However, I want to target all classes of `.title` and hence I thought I could use a `querySelectorAll` and a `forEach`. I am clearly not understanding how this works.

```
var paras = document.querySelectorAll('.title');
paras.forEach(function wrapLastWord(elem) {

      const textContent = elem.textContent.split(" ");
      const lastWord = textContent.pop();

      // if the sentence is more than 1 word, wrap the last word with a span. If it's only 1 word, return it without being wrapped by a span
      const updatedContent = textContent.join(" ") + (textContent.length > 0 ? ` <span class='last-word'>${lastWord}</span>` : lastWord);

      elem.innerHTML = updatedContent;
    }

    wrapLastWord(paras)
                  
})
```

Could anyone please give me some pointers to get this working, or suggest an alternative direction

Answer (score 2):

To begin you have a syntax error in your second line missing an "

```
<h1 class="title>A long <span class="last-word">tile</span></h1>
<h2 class="title>A long <span class="last-word">tile</span></h2>
```

should be this

```
<h1 class="title">A long <span class="last-word">tile</span></h1>
<h2 class="title">A long <span class="last-word">tile</span></h2>
```

As for getting the value using javascript you can simply do

```
const spanText = document.querySelector('.last-word).innerText
// this will find the first match
console.log(spanText)

//if you want to find all of the ".last-words"

const lastWords = document.querySelectorAll('.last-word')
console.log(lastWords, "<-array like object")

lastWords.forEach((word)=> {
  console.log(word.innerText)
})
```

As for your function

```
var paras = document.querySelectorAll(".title");
console.log(paras);
paras.forEach(function wrapLastWord(elem) {

  const textContent = elem.innerText.split(" ");
  console.log(textContent, ' textContent')
  const lastWord = textContent.pop();
  console.log(lastWord, 'last word')
  // // if the sentence is more than 1 word, wrap the last word with a span. If it's only 1 word, return it without being wrapped by a span
  const updatedContent = ` <span class='last-word'>${lastWord}</span>`;     
  console.log(updatedContent, 'updatedContent')
})
```

You've created `updatedContent` as you can see in your log, but now you have to decide what you want to do with it.  Maybe use one of the `append` methods you can look at the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) and explore the append method if you want to add it to your page

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the contents of `h1` and `h2` are not available, hence why I'm trying to target with JS

Comment: if you want the h1 then just do 
 `const h1Text = document.querySelector('.title').innerText`

Comment: I want the contents of all `.titles` classes

Comment: Oh my bad I made a mistake, I updated my original answer using the `.querySelectorAll`

Comment: Sorry if I do not understand the answer. Perhaps my question is not as clear as I thought it was? I want to find each class, in this case, `.title`. Split the contents of that element and then wrap the last word with a span class. This is shown in my first code example. I am trying to adapt this code, so it targets all classes of `.title`. My code example only targets to first `.title` it finds.

Comment: Updated my answer for you

Comment: Thanks, you led me to an anwser. If you'd like to amend your anwser, I'll mark it accordingly. ```const paras = document.querySelectorAll('.title');

paras.forEach(function wrapLastWord(elem) {
  const textContent = elem.textContent.split(" ");
  const lastWord = textContent.pop();


  const updatedContent = textContent.join(" ") + (textContent.length > 0 ? ` <span class='last-word'>${lastWord}</span>` : lastWord);

  elem.innerHTML = updatedContent;
})

Answer (score 0):

@JimithyPicker Thanks, you led me to an answer.

My final code is as follows:

```
const paras = document.querySelectorAll(".title");

paras.forEach(function wrapLastWord(elem) {
    const textContent = elem.textContent.split(" ");
    const lastWord = textContent.pop();

    // if the sentence is more than 1 word, wrap the last word with a span. If it's only 1 word, return it without being wrapped by a span
    const updatedContent = textContent.join(" ") + (textContent.length > 0 ? ` <span class='last-word'>${lastWord}</span>` : lastWord);

    elem.innerHTML = updatedContent;
});
```